# WooCommerce: have to refresh page before I can update item quantity?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

When I add an item to the cart, the following code will check if the item already exists in the cart, if it does, delete the product from the cart and add the item again but with the new quantity.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'woo_custom_add_to_cart_before' );

function woo_custom_add_to_cart_before( $cart_item_data ) {
$cart = WC()->instance()->cart;
$id = $_POST['product_id'];
$cart_id = $cart->generate_cart_id($id);
$cart_item_id = $cart->find_product_in_cart($cart_id);

if($cart_item_id){
$cart->set_quantity($cart_item_id,0);
$cart->add_to_cart( $cart_item_id );
}
return true;
}
```

This works fine, but doesn't allow me to add the item for a second time. For example an item is added using ajax, I then adjust the quantity and click the add to cart button for a second time but nothing happens - the cart is not updated, I have to refresh the page before I can edit the same item again. How can I customise my code to edit the quantity multiple times without the need to refresh?

Comment: Why not use WooCommerce's built-in add-to-cart functionality? Otherwise, you should look into setting up a proper WordPress AJAX hook: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: After reading through many tutorials and the link @rnevius posted, I'm still unable to make this work... It does appear to be a problem with AJAX. After viewing the form data of AJAX once it's submitted it shows the correct quantity on the first call, however when I click the add to cart button once again I think the item is removed from cart and then AJAX re-adds the item but the form data hasn't been updated and still has the old item quantity. After days of trying to find a solution, I feel I've hit a brick wall... Can anyone please help?